# Использование this в анонимном классе OnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Почему в данном случае нельзя использовать `this`?

```
btnNewActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Потому что, this (дословно переводится "этот") - это указатель на объект из которого он был вызван. В данном случае this вызывается из объекта View.OnClickListener(). А в Intent нужно передавать context, поэтому нужно писать getApplicationContext().

Comment: Понял,спасибо!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае `this` у вас указывает на объект `OnClickListener`, а он не является потомком класса `Context`. Но, если вы, например, задавали `listener` внутри класса `Activity`, то можно написать так:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

btnNewActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что вы работаете в анонимном классе. Чтобы получить текущий объект внешнего класса, используйте конструкцию `ИмяВнешнегоКласса.this`